# disable a container, and all the elements inside it

Tags: jquery, html

Good afternoon, I'm trying to find a container that can disable all the elements inside it, not just input's, but also image and other elements that do not have the disabled property ...
I would not like to hide the container, but disable it ... do you know that there is a container that I can do it? thank you

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnHabilitar').click(function () {
        $("#menu").prop("disabled", false); 
    });
    $('#btnDesabilitar').click(function () {
        $("#menu").prop("disabled", true);
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        var container = $("#menu");

        if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $("#menu").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });

    $('#img1').click(function () {
        alert('clicou imagem');
    });
});
```

```html
<fieldset id="menu" >
        <div class="container-fluid" >
            <div class="row">
                <input type="button" class="col-md-2 btn btn-primary" id="botao1" value="botao 1" />
                <input type="button" class="col-md-2 btn btn-primary" id="botao2" value="botao 2" />
                <input type="button" class="col-md-2 btn btn-primary" id="botao3" value="botao 3" />
                <input type="button" class="col-md-2 btn btn-primary" id="botao4" value="botao 4" />
                <input type="button" class="col-md-2 btn btn-primary" id="botao5" value="botao 5" />
                <input type="button" class="col-md-2 btn btn-primary" id="botao6" value="botao 6" />
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <img src="img/css3.png" id="img1" style="width:200px; height:200px;"/>
                <img src="img/bootstrap.png" style="width:200px; height:200px;" />
                <img src="img/html.png" style="width:200px; height:200px;" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: HTML structure (ie. a container) cannot act upon anything... Only javascript/jQuery would be able to disable elements within a container - and that needs a trigger. So what event will trigger the jQuery to disable all elements in a container, and how will it recognize such a container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `opacity` property of CSS3 and set it to be half of normal. This will make the container itself and all child elements look like they are disable. You can then also use `pointer-events: none` to avoid all click events.

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j1dwmgu7/2/) for you that disables the whole menu. You can add those CSS3 rules to some class and then use `addClass("className")` function to add it to the menu with some button clicked

Comment: .desabilitado {
    pointer-events:none;
    opacity:.2;
}

worked perfectly, thank you

Comment: You are welcome! I'm glad to hear that my answer helped